# Django POST 405 method not allowed unless rule comes first

Tags: django, django-urls

My Django (2.2.5) app has the following `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import re_path
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    re_path('^$|signin', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='signin.html'), name='signin'),
    path('forgot', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='forgot.html'), name='forgot_pass'),
    path('app', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='core.html'), name='core'),

    path('try_signin', views.try_signin, name='try_signin'),      

] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

The first 3 rules work fine and serve up the respective HTML content. The 4th rule is for a POST request, but the request causes the following error:

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /try_signin
>   Method Not Allowed: /try_signin
>   [30/Sep/2019 14:20:38] "POST /try_signin HTTP/1.1" 405 0

However if I reorder the URL rules so that the POST rule comes first, then it works fine. There's no conflict in the rules that I can see. I'm new to Django and still learning but I'd like to understand why re-ordering the rules avoids the error, or if there's something else I'm doing/not doing that caused the error.

This is my `views.py`:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from time import sleep
import logging
import json

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def try_signin(request):
    user_email = request.POST.get('user', None)
    password = request.POST.get('pass', None)
    log.info("Signin attempt ==> [%s] [%s]" % (user_email, password))
    sleep(2)
    data = {
        'success': False
    }
    log.info("Returning response ==> %s" % json.dumps(data))
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Also, adding `@require_POST` decorator to the `try_signin` function above still causes the error. As I said earlier, it does work if I reorder the rule to appear first in `url_patterns`.

Comment: Please add the view try_signin to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re_path('^$|signin', ...)` matches the url `/try_signin`. So when you POST to this URL, it goes to the `TemplateView` for **signin.html** which only accepts GET requests.